Dynamic index.html content for single page app
I have a .NET 8 app with a vue3 frontend. Out of the box it serves index.html from its dev server:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>

I would like to intercept this to be able to server side render things like the <title> tag dynamically.
How can I control the returned index.html content, both in development and production build? Either using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions that I use now or the more up to date(?) approach with AspNetCore.SpaProxy.
Should I do a custom app.MapGet("/", () => ... return custom index.html or is there any support for this in the nuget packages?
What I have so far, seems ok at first glance. Not sure if it's robust enough or I missed anything covered by the microsoft extensions:
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
   FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ClientApp/dist"))
});

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
   if (context.GetEndpoint() != null || Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
   {
       await next();
       return;
   }

   var htmlGenerator = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IndexFileGenerator>();

   context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
   await context.Response.WriteAsync(htmlGenerator.GetHtml());
});


It seems your approach for intercepting requests and dynamically generating the index.html file is on the right track.

@Rena  do you see any possible improvements?

wouldn't regenerating the index.html all the time defeat the purpose of a SPA? Do this on the frontend at the most use an endpoint to collect any data the frontend doesnt already have. Doesnt sound like the right approach for this subject. what is the result you are hoping for?

@danielRICADO It's not regenerated "all the time", it's once per visit just as if it's served from static files, with the difference being some dynamic tags in it. That's not very clear in my question though, but the whole point is to have the title and meta tags server side rendered for crawlers and bots that can't render javascript, e.g. share a page on linkedin, teams etc.

ah I get ya, most of the main search engines do execute the javascript and then take  the final render before indexing it nowdays. So only need to worry about that if you're looking to support some minor search engine.

@danielRICADO Right, it's more about sharing on social media and similar that becomes an issue.

hmm does sound like some SSR is required for what you'er trying to do, maybe react-snap could help you https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-snap  or react-helmet sorry not sure how else you could generate these if dynamic og:metatags arent picked up by social media sites

@danielRICADO it's ok, my solution works fine. I just wanted to draw some additional attention to it for feedback

Modify HTML Before Serving
// Serving static files for production (after Vue build)
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ClientApp/dist")),
    RequestPath = string.Empty // or any appropriate path if needed
});

// Intercept and modify the index.html in non-static paths
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.GetEndpoint() != null || Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
    {
        // Proceed to static file handling (CSS, JS, etc.)
        await next();
        return;
    }

    // Assuming you have a custom service that generates the dynamic index.html
    var htmlGenerator = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IndexFileGenerator>();

    // Optionally, you can pass request data to the generator, such as the route or user info
    string title = "Default Title"; // Default value, could be dynamic
    var path = context.Request.Path.Value.ToLower();
    if (path.Contains("/about"))
    {
        title = "About Us";
    }
    else if (path.Contains("/contact"))
    {
        title = "Contact Us";
    }

    // Generate the HTML dynamically with the updated title
    var html = htmlGenerator.GetHtml(title);

    // Return the modified HTML as response
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(html);
});

IndexFileGenerator:
This is a service that you would need to implement to generate the modified index.html content. It should return the HTML content as a string with any dynamic changes (such as modifying the <title> or other meta tags).
Routing Logic: You can pass information from the request (like the current path) into the IndexFileGenerator to modify the content dynamically. You could also incorporate other data, such as user profile information, for a more customized experience.
IndexFileGenerator Implementation
public class IndexFileGenerator
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

    public IndexFileGenerator(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    public string GetHtml(string title)
    {
        // Read the index.html from the build folder (e.g., dist/index.html)
        var indexPath = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "ClientApp", "dist", "index.html");
        var htmlContent = File.ReadAllText(indexPath);

        // Replace the <title> tag dynamically
        htmlContent = htmlContent.Replace("<title>Vite App</title>", $"<title>{title}</title>");

        // You could also modify other parts of the HTML (meta tags, scripts, etc.) here

        return htmlContent;
    }
}


Sooo... this is basically my code with comments? :D

@Johan Yes I have tried to use your code

And how does this solve the issue then?

looks a lot like the question just got dumped into chatgpt on this answer hey.
